# VS2010 Unable to do a database schema comparison

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, schema

I have a VS 2010 solution I've been doing schema comparisons with a DB 2008 project.. It's been working against my local SQL as well as a dev/staging database.  i checked out the project on another computer, and now when trying to compare down to the local express db I get the following error.  "You cannot write updates to the target when you compare the specified types of schema models."  What does this mean?  The only link I've found in Google seems to point to an incorrect project type which isn't the case here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit misleading, but if you look closely when you try to export to the editor there is another warning message that is quickly replaced by the one you cite. Call up your Error List View and you will see why you cannot write your updates. Resolve the validation errors and you should be good to go.